# Is there any patch  available for EXT3 file system to compress?

Tags: ext3

I read that the patch available for the file system EXT-3 but i could-not trace the patch. So my humble request is that if anyone aware of the locality of the  patch for the EXT-3 file system please let me know where its available...

Thanks,

Comment: Did you, y'know, even *try* to "trace the patch"? Nope, you didn't: [FIRST DAMN RESULT for "ext3 compression" (on Wikipedia, no less!)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ext3#Compression): "Support for transparent compression is available as an unofficial patch for ext3. This patch is a direct port of e2compr and still needs further development, it compiles and boots well with upstream kernels[citation needed] but journaling is not implemented yet. The current patch is named e3compr" - followed by the link to that damn patch! But that would require a tool to search the Net,and no such thing exists.

Comment: Hi @ Piskvor, i already read about the article on Wikipedia regarding the EXT3 compression is under development yet but i am little bit confused so in-order to ensure it asked for help....Anyway thanks for your suggestion...

Comment: It is rather useful to say so in the question itself: "I've tried this and that, and read that site" - to prevent a reply like "Well first try this and that, and read that site".

Comment: Hi @Piskvor, I will keep it in mind. If i post again i will do so.Thanks for ur suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://sourceforge.net/projects/e3compr/

However, I believe btrfs might be worth looking at if you want to use compression.